# Как переключать .active между блоками?

Tags: javascript, toggle

```
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="main">
    <div class="block red active"></div>
    <div class="block black"></div>
    <div class="block green"></div>
</div>

<script>

var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var block = document.querySelector(".block");

 btn.onclick = function() {

    block.classList.toggle("active");
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bpdcy5vh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать все блоки c помощью [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), и менять активный по индексу в коллекции:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
var activeBlock = document.querySelector(".block.active");
btn.onclick = function() {
  var index = [].indexOf.call(blocks, activeBlock);
  // Следующий
  if (index == blocks.length - 1) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    ++index;
  }
  activeBlock = blocks[index];
  blocks.forEach((block, i) => block.classList[i==index?'add':'remove']('active'))
};
```

```css
.main{
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: grey;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: red;
 display: none;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
.black{
 background-color: black;
}
.green{
 background-color: green;
}
.active{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.btn'),
    blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block')),
    pointer = 0;
    
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Убираем прошлый блок
  blocks[pointer].classList.remove('active');
  
  if(pointer + 1 >= blocks.length)
    pointer = 0;
  else
    pointer++;
  
  // Отмечаем новый блок
  blocks[pointer].classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.main{
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: grey;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: red;
 display: none;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
.black{
 background-color: black;
}
.green{
 background-color: green;
}
.active{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="main">
    <div class="block red active"></div>
    <div class="block black"></div>
    <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
```